# Determine if image is duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is the function that previews and uploads the image into the form:

```
//Process to upload and Preview Images being uploaded   
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(a) {
        var files = a.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
        var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
        var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
             if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {                  
                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {

                    var f = files[i];
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.fileName = files[i].name;
                    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                        var file = e.target;

                            $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
                            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" + 
                            "<br />" + "<span class=\"fontImage\">" + file.fileName + "</span><span class=\"remove\">X</span>" + "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
                            $('#files').val('');

                        /*Increment/Decrement Count of files loaded*/
                        var c = $(".pip").length;

                        if (c == 1)
                            $("#replaceText").text(c + " image file uploaded");
                        if (c > 1)
                            $("#replaceText").text(c + " image files uploaded");

                        $(".remove").on('click', function(){
                            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                                if($(".pip").length > 1){   
                                    c--;
                                    $("#replaceText").text(c + " image files uploaded");
                                }
                                else if($(".pip").length == 1){
                                    c--;
                                    $("#replaceText").text(c + " image file uploaded");
                                }
                                else{
                                    $("#replaceText").text("No file chosen");
                                }

                        });
                        /********************************/
                        if($(".pip").length > 1){
                            $("#delete_all").show();
                            $("#delete_all").css('margin-top',"10px");
                        }
                        else
                            $("#delete_all").hide();
                    });         
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //alert("WARNING: Invalid image extension(s)");
            document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = "<h4>WARNING: Invalid image extension(s).</h4>";
            document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>Upload a image that has a valid extension(s).</p>";
            document.getElementById("myform").focus();
            $('#files').val('');
            $("#invalidModal").modal();

            return false        
        }
   });
} 
else {
    //alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API.");
    document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = "<h4>ERROR: Does not support API</h4>";
    document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>Your browser doesn't support to File API. Update your current browser.</p>";
    document.getElementById("myform").focus();
    $("#invalidModal").modal();

    return false
}
```

However, what I would like to achieve next is to determine whether an image that is being loaded to the form is a duplicate. What I mean is if the previous image that is already loaded to the form is being attempted to be loaded to the form again, to throw an error. Otherwise, to accept the new image. I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: uploaded? like already exists are was selected more than once?

Comment: @epascarello: Already Exists. Ex. I choose img1 and then I attempt to select img1 again although it already exists. If I attempt to load the same image again, throw an error. I hope I explain myself better this time. If not, I do apolgize

Comment: Just a name match?  Keep a database table of all names, probably with a user field since your kitty.jpg will not be my kitty.jpg.  To check for kitty1.jpg duplicating kitty2.jpg you'd generate a hash for each image.

Comment: @DaveS: Yes, just a name match.

Comment: @DaveS: Will see if I can do that.